# Reducing Memory on Binary Search Tree Insertion

Tags: time-complexity, binary-search-tree, space-complexity, insertion

So I have just written a solution to binary tree insertion. It seems to be effecient but takes up so much space in comparison to others. I am wondering how I can get better at reducing space complexity in my solutions for DSA. Thanks!

Here is what I wrote:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public TreeNode insertIntoBST(TreeNode root, int val) {

        if(root == null) {
            root = new TreeNode();
            root.val = val;
            return root;
        }
        if(val > root.val){
            root.right = insertIntoBST(root.right, val);
        }
        else if (val < root.val){
            root.left = insertIntoBST(root.left, val);
        }

            return root; 
        }
   }
```

Comment: If you are referring to sites like LeetCode, then realise that the memory reported is not only about the auxiliary memory that your code is allocating. You'll get reports like saying 45 MB was used, while other executions "only" used 44 MB. There is not much you can learn from that information. If you measured the memory yourself, then that would be more useful. Please provide that information and your calculation method.